# How do I obtain the Lagrangian in standard for using action?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, action

I have action as shown below
$$S=\int \mathrm{d}t \int \mathrm{d}x^3  \bar\psi\left(i\partial_t\psi +\frac1{2m}\bar\nabla^2\psi-V(x)\psi\right)$$

How do I manipulate it to obtain the Lagrangian density in Standard form
$$\mathcal{L}\left(\{\varphi_r\},\{\partial_\mu\varphi_r\}  \right)$$

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but I would suggest using integration by parts (and getting rid of the total derivatives).

Answer (score 2):

We have $$S=∫dtL=∫_{}dt∫dx\cal{L}.$$ Integration by parts (see the above remark by Hunter) then leads to  $${\cal{L}}=iψ^{∗}∂_{t}ψ-(1/(2m))∂_{x}ψ^{∗}∂_{x}ψ-ψ^{∗}V(x)ψ,$$ which is the Lagrangian density for a complex non-relativistic field with potential $V$.

Comment: time derrvative and spatial derrivative should have same power 2

Comment: That is not true in the non-relativistic case. See Tong, "Lectures on Quantum Field Theory", p 48, eq. (2.106) http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html